# Obtain all the players born in a particular month in Sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a players table which contains the following attributes

```
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name text not null,birth_date date not null
```

I want a query which can give me a list of all the players born in a particular month say May of 1986.

How could this be achieved? I tried using the date and time functions provided in SQLite but they were of no use.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT p.name, p.birth_date
    FROM Player p
        WHERE p.birth_date > '1986-04-30'
            AND p.birth_date < '1986-06-01';
```

(untested)

Comment: The second condition could also be: `AND p.birth_date < '1986-06-01'`. It's the same thing when dealing with dates but better if you have datetimes.

Comment: That was the original condition I had, but when @Catcall edited my answer to properly quote the dates, they also changed the edge conditions.

Comment: Yes, I changed Matt Ball's edge conditions. He originally wrote  `p.birth_date > 1986-04-30 and p.birth_date < 1986-05-01`. I see now that he probably meant `< '1986-06-01'`. I'll try to use a lighter touch in the future. : )

Comment: @Catcall: you're right - I just didn't type what I meant. Thanks for the fixes :)

Answer (score 2):

I *think* this should work. I haven't tried it:

```
SELECT _id, name, birth_date 
FROM players 
WHERE strftime('%m',birth_date) = '05' AND  strftime('%Y',birth_date) = '1986'
```

Comment: Matt Ball's version can use an index; your version will have to evaluate strftime() twice for each row. That's an observation, not a criticism. Most of the people I deal with think in terms of months and years when they're dealing with questions like this. And then they turn their work over to me for tweaking.

Comment: Yeah I like that method better. I had one of those "d'oh, why didn't I think of that" moments.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would this work: `... WHERE strftime('%Y %m',birth_date) = '1986 05'`?

Comment: Yeah I think that should. I'm not able to test it now but I don't see why not. Still probably better off using your original implementation. This would probably only be better in the case where you were just looking for the month, and didn't care about the year.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.name
     , p.birth_date
FROM Player p
WHERE p.birth_date >= '1986-05-01'
  AND p.birth_date < date('1986-05-01','+1 month') 
;
```